# If statement yields "Identifier expected" Error and will not run

Tags: javascript, if-statement, identifier

I am very new to js so i apologize if i'm just dumb :p

```
  var numberstring = String('1');

            if (d1 =< tsticks) {
                ...numberstring = numberstring +  String(', ') + String('d1')
            } if (d2 =< tsticks) {
                ...numberstring = numberstring + String(', ') + String('d2')
            }
            
            
            // if the first number is a deathnumber, warn the player to not go first
            if (tsticks != 1 && tsticks != d1 && tsticks != d2 && tsticks != d3 && tsticks != d4 && tsticks != d5 && tsticks != d6 && tsticks != d7 && tsticks != d8 && tsticks != d9 && tsticks != d10 &&  tsticks != d11 && tsticks != d12 && tsticks != d13 && tsticks != d14 && tsticks != d15 && tsticks != d16 && tsticks != d17 && tsticks != d18 && tsticks != d19 && tsticks != d20 && !isNaN(st) && !isNaN(tsticks));{
                document.getElementById('turn').innerHTML = String('Go first')
            
            
                //if the first number is not a death number, tell the player they should go first
            } else if (!isNaN(st) && !isNaN(tsticks)){
                document.getElementById('turn').innerHTML = String('Do not go First')
            }
```

d2 is a defined variable, and so is tsticks.
The goal is to append an additional string to an already defined string if an if statement succeeds.
VS code spits out these errors:

- Identifier expected. javascript [3,34]
- Identifier expected. javascript [5,22]
- Identifier expected. javascript [5,36]
- '=>' expected. javascript [6,38]
- Declaration or statement expected. javascript [6,21]
- Declaration or statement expected. javascript [16,19]

All line numbers are in referce to the code shown above

Also i have no idea how to use stack overflow...

Comment: Please post code (and error messages) as text, not as links to paintings of parts of it. You can [edit] your question to improve it.

Comment: Just figured out how to do that. like i said, im very new to stack

Comment: So it seems you have multiple errors in your code. I recommend you to look up every error message and the corresponding line number to understand what is going wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add the actual code instead of image so it would be easier to reply. Try

```
numberstring += ", " + d1;
```

**Updated:**

```js
var tsticks = 5;
var d1 = 1;
var d2 = 2;
var d3 = d4 = d5 = d6 = d7 = d8 = d9 = d10 = d11 = d12 = d13 = d14 = d15 = d16 = d17 = d18 = d19 = d20 = st = 1;
var numberstring = '1';

if (d1 <= tsticks) {
    numberstring += ", " + d1;
} else if (d2 <= tsticks) {
    numberstring += ", " + d2;
}
            
            
// if the first number is a deathnumber, warn the player to not go first
if (tsticks != 1 && tsticks != d1 && tsticks != d2 && tsticks != d3 && tsticks != d4 && tsticks != d5 && tsticks != d6 && tsticks != d7 && tsticks != d8 && tsticks != d9 && tsticks != d10 &&  tsticks != d11 && tsticks != d12 && tsticks != d13 && tsticks != d14 && tsticks != d15 && tsticks != d16 && tsticks != d17 && tsticks != d18 && tsticks != d19 && tsticks != d20 && !isNaN(st) && !isNaN(tsticks)) {
  document.getElementById('turn').innerHTML = 'Go first';
} else if (!isNaN(st) && !isNaN(tsticks)){
  document.getElementById('turn').innerHTML = 'Do not go First';
}
```

```html
<div id="turn"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you! this works just fine, but as someone who is still learning js, what was wrong with the original code? just so i know for the future :p

Comment: first of all you need to define all the variables that you will use as you can see in the first five lines also as you can see '=<' should be replaced with '<='  and '...' that dots is called spread syntax, so there is a lot to learn)) and if it answer was helpfull you can mark it as accepted

Comment: + there was that `;` between the really long `if()` and the `{` that follows it, which probably terminated the `if()` instead of running what should have been the 'true' block.